Intuition for parallel memory use in R
There are a lot of questions about parallel computing in R but I couldn't find one that seems similar to my problem.
In my case, I'm using the searchk() function in R's stm package on a very large stm object (corpus). The object is about 8.9 GB in size. My goal is to find the optimal number of topics between 8 and 26, which involves some very taxing computation.
To save time, stm provides an option for use of multiple cores (cores=1). First I tried a single core across the full topic search range (8:26). The process ran for 3 weeks (and got to about 40% complete) before finally crashing. This is obviously untenable, but searching across the full topic range on 2+ cores exceeds my system's total memory. Nor is it recommended to perform searchk() on a subset of the data.
It occurs to me there might be a better way to split the problem up: running the search on batches of topics, where each batch is analyzed sequentially, and within each batch, multiple cores perform the computation.
Assuming that's a sensible approach, here is a function which I think should accomplish it:
library(furrr)
library(future)

options(future.globals.maxSize = 9000 * 1024^2)
# plan(multicore, workers = 1) 
plan(sequential) # is this actually equivalent to workers=1?

run_searchK <- function(i) {
  start_time <- Sys.time()  # Start timer
  
  k_search <- c(i, i + 1) # Create a batch of size 2
  
  set.seed(888) # Set seed
  
  kResult <- searchK(dfm.stm$documents, prevalence = ~s(Year) + predictor, dfm.stm$vocab,
                     K = k_search, data = dfm.stm$meta, heldout.seed = 888, 
                     cores = 8, verbose = FALSE)  
  
  gc(verbose = FALSE)
  
  end_time <- Sys.time()  # End timer
  time_taken <- end_time - start_time
  
  return(kResult)
  
}

# Set k range (8:24) and confirm batch size (2)
i_values <- seq(8, 23, by = 2) 

set.seed(888)
results <- future_map(i_values, run_searchK, .options=furrr_options(seed = TRUE))

# Make combined batches viewable in a dataframe
combined_results <- purrr::map_df(results, ~ .x$results)

Other than arbitrarily selecting parameters, I'd like to understand better how to optimize the number of cores and batch size so that I get the speed boost without exceeding ~90GB of memory. However, I also don't know if it's possible to benchmark on a subset of the data since memory footprint is expected to scale nonlinearly with searchK().
Intuitively, how do I find the best batch size/core allocation? Is there a better way of setting it up given the information I have ex ante?
System specs:

Mac OS Sonoma
12-core M2 Processor (with OpenMP enabled)
96 GB RAM (-6GB background)


Here is what I learned from randomly experimenting with parameters. Two things impact the results: k length (topic search range) and ncores. The number of active processes is determined by max(cores, k length), and the memory impact is purely a function of stm object size * number of processes. Interesting, batching k is worse for runtime (??), all else equal! So if you're dealing with a large stm object that you shouldn't subset, you're stuck with a choice between reducing k length (especially higher-order k values) or reducing ncores. There may be a workaround; I haven't found it.
